# How to use go-swagger to define an attachment download

Tags: string, file, download, attachment, go-swagger

I am using `go-swagger` to download attachments. These are small multi-line files, and there is just a browser on the other end.
I tried defining the response as `'string'`, but can find no way to populate the payload with multiline text, it arrives with "\r\n" instead of newlines.  I also tried `'string'` format `'binary'`, but then the client sees a response containing a `Reader{}`.  My content `yaml` for the 200 response looks like this:

```
headers:
        Content-Disposition:
          type: string
          pattern: attachment; filename="attachement.txt"
        Content-Type:
          type: string
          pattern: application/octet-stream
      schema:
        type: string
```

I also tried `'string'` format `'byte'`, but I don't want a `base64` encoded response. 
Any advice on this?

This is what I have tried so far:

trying "string" format "byte"...

```
  payload := bytes.NewBufferString("first line")
    payload.WriteByte(13)
    payload.WriteByte(10)
    payload.WriteString("second line")
    payload.WriteByte(13)
    payload.WriteByte(10)
    resp := responses.NewGetResponseInfoOK()
    resp.SetPayload(payload)
  // fails.. will not accept payload other than strfmt.Bas64
```

trying "string"

```
payload := bytes.NewBufferString("first line")
    payload.WriteByte(13)
    payload.WriteByte(10)
    payload.WriteString("second line")
    payload.WriteByte(13)
    payload.WriteByte(10)
    resp := responses.NewGetResponseInfoOK()
    resp.SetPayload(payload.String())
  // accepts payload, but 13/10 get converted into \r\n
```

trying "string" format "binary"

```
type nopCloser struct {
      io.Reader
  }

  func (nopCloser) Close() error { return nil }


  payload := bytes.NewBufferString("first line")
    payload.WriteByte(13)
    payload.WriteByte(10)
    payload.WriteString("second line")
    payload.WriteByte(13)
    payload.WriteByte(10)
    resp := responses.NewGetResponseInfoOK()
    resp.SetPayload(nopCloser(payload))

  // accepts payload, but the browser sees a Reader{}
```

Comment: Please show us some code and what you've tried so far.

Comment: I found the answer. I had used the text producer in the yaml file, I needed to make that into a octet-stream producer for this response by adding:         produces: 
        - application/octet-stream
 To the response yaml and re-building

Comment: Curiously, the above works for CURL client, but using a GO HTTP client still returns me a "Reader{}" - where ioutil.ReadAll() gives an empty string. This appears to be a limitation?

Comment: Anyone get this working? I too am interested....

Answer (score 2):

To reiterate the comment on the question, anyone who's trying to simply create an endpoint which allows for file download in go-swagger, just add an `produces application/octet-stream` to the method.